# How Do I Find Out What Intent To Listen For In Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner, intentfilter

I'm developing an app which I'd like to be launched when a specific action is made. In this case, it's when the built in barcode scanner scans something.
When the scanner does scan something, I get the usual dialogue asking which app I'd like to use. The options are Google Chrome or Browser at the moment.
I've looked for some kind of documentation on Google Chrome to try to find out which intents it listens for, but to no avail.

I was wondering whether there's an easier way to find out which intent-filters to use?

Comment: Are you using zxing?

Comment: No, I'm using a device with an integrated laser barcode scanner. It has no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you actually need to know which intent-filter is defined in the apps that are optionable from the Barcode scanner after scan, so you can define them in your app.
You can try using an app such as this one:

[Stanley (Package Explorer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.packageexplorer)

and then use it to view the Manifest of one of this apps and see how it's defined there, so you can use it in your app.

Comment: Correct, Google Chrome and Browser are the options after a scan. By "I need to know what intents they're listening for" I meant exactly what you said. It sounds like the app could be the solution. I don't have the device with me right now, so I will let you know as soon as I try it. Thank you for now :)